# How to pass multiple generic functors to class constructors, when the the possible functors that can be used may have different number of arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, clang, functor

I'm facing an issue with C++, which, quite possible may just be a restriction in the language itself, and thus this issue may not have a solution.

I have multiple functions, which resemble the following (there are much more than 2 by the way)

```
template <class Input, class Output>
Output A(Input in) {
   ...
   return ...
}

template <class Input1, class Input2, class Output>
Output B(Input1 in1, Input2 in2) {
   ...
   return ...
}
```

Now, these functions have to be passed into a class constructor and stored in the class as a functor, however, we don't know which functor is being passed into the constructor, and hence we don't know the number of arguments of said functor. This means I'm facing two problems:

1. I can't find a way to templatize the constructor to accept any functor.
2. I can't find a way to store the functor in the same templatized class.

The problem I face is that I don't know how to correctly templatize `Inputs1`, `Output1`, `Inputs2` and `Output2`.

```
template <?>
class C {

   std::function<Output1(Inputs1)> f1;
   std::function<Output2(Inputs2)> f2;

public:

   template <?>
   C(std::function<Output1(Inputs1)> f1, std::function<Output2(Inputs2)> f2)
      : f1(f1), f2(f2) {}

}
```

I don't have to use `std::function`, any solution that can be done without it is fine too.

Can this be done as a template lambda, or will that too, have the exact same effect as any normal function.

The only alternative I can imagine is having all the functions as classes with an `operator()` member, and the classes all extend some other empty class which we can use as a parameter in the main class.

```
class Functor {}

class A : public Functor {
   public: operator()() {...}
}

class C {

   Functor f1;
   Functor f2;

public:

   C(Functor f1, Functor f2) : f1(f1), f2(f2) {}

}
```

Is this viable C++ code?

The class layout is pretty flexible, so any solution where a class can accept a function which it will use later in its execution is acceptable.

I'm using clang++ -std=c++14

Comment: When you want to call the stored function, how will you know whether it's `A` or `B` and thus what arguments to pass to it?

Comment: The functions take one main argument, along with certain parameters that can be determined at compile time. So either pass those in templates, or something that would seem more logical is having the functions as classes with constructors taking those parameters along with an operator() calling that main variable

Comment: The way you've abstracted your question makes it pretty much impossible to answer it. Try to crystallize it a bit, especially in respect to the way you would like to use your `C` class.

Comment: how are you going to call the functors once passed to C ?